# Install Chef server and managed node on a same host

Tags: chef

I have a host which I want to manage via Chef, but I have no dedicated host for Chef-server.

Which way is better?

1. Install Chef-server on a laptop which I will use as a workstation
2. Install Chef-server on a same host with managed node
3. Install Chef-server into docker container and manage another docker container on the same host. (Same as 2 but packed with dockers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef.io has a hosted chef server that you can use for free for up to 25 nodes.

Or you can write your cookbook in a way that it uses chef-solo or chef-zero

Chef-zero is the preferred method. Basically it spins up a local chef server on the same host that the client runs on.

Comment: It looks like they don't provide server hosting now for free https://www.chef.io/pricing/

Comment: Sorry, I miss it, they have free account with hosted server.

Answer (score 2):

Use Chef client's [local mode](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#run-in-local-mode). This does not require a Chef Server then.

Comment: But then I can't manage a node from laptop.

Comment: You can push the cookbook code to a git repo that you pull on the node.